# The magnetic moments of Hadrons

Tags: particle-physics, magnetic-moment

So I am very confused about how to find the magnetic moment of a arbitrary hadron.

I have found out that the magnetic moment of a quark is given by:

$\mu_q = \frac{e_qM_p}{m_q}\mu_N$

Where: $e_q, M_p, m_q$ are the quark charge, the proton mass, and the quark mass. Respectivly.

But what do I do when I have a Hadron? For example. one consisting of $ \Sigma^+ $= uus?

Should I just add them up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost. You have to write the proper symmetrized wavefunction and use it to take the expectation value of $\hat\mu_{1}+\hat\mu_{2}+\hat\mu_{3}$. Each operator acts on one slot, like this:

$$\hat\mu_1\left|a,b,c\right>
=\mu_a\left|a,b,c\right>\\
\hat\mu_2\left|a,b,c\right>
=\mu_b\left|a,b,c\right>\\
\hat\mu_3\left|a,b,c\right>
=\mu_c\left|a,b,c\right>$$

Check out Halzen & Martin, I think it's worked out there.